# Nonlocal perimeter of level sets

Tags: fractional-calculus, isoperimetric-problems

Let $u \in W^{s,1}(B)$ be given and $k < l$ be two numbers, then I am looking for a way to bound the following term from above. Here $B$ is the euclidean ball.
$$
\int_{B: u < k} \int_{B:u>l} \frac{1}{|x-y|^{N+s}} dx dy,
$$
where $s \in (0,1)$. Can one get an upper bound (preferably sharp) in terms of the measure of the two level sets?

I see that this is somehow related to fractional isoperimetric inequality, but this is a subject I am not familiar with. So any suggestions or references will be very helpful.